# Can an application data be accessed without content provider?

Tags: android

According to Google's documentation, apps can access the data which belongs to other apps with the help of content providers.

Can this data be accessed / modified without content providers?

Comment: `apps can access the data which belongs to other apps with the help of content providers.` No. No app has acces to the data of other apps. And there exist no 'content robbers'. What apps can do however is using a content prvider to serve their data to other apps.

Answer (score -1):

Content Providers provide you the data from sqlite . You could query and insert raw sqlite without providers